# Finding a link with a non-breaking space inside it with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I'm getting better finding links without any id or name but this one has me stumped and a Google search hasn't helped. I'm trying to click on a link using Selenium webdriver in Java.

```
 <a class="mainleftlinks" onclick="return TrackChanges();" href="/chcfweb/sbc/administration/aac/leftlinks.do?linkid=040000" styleclass="mainleftlinks">&nbsp;&nbsp;Administrative &nbsp;&nbsp;Claiming</a>
```

Not sure what those nbsp things  are. If you look at the application the link/button looks like this:

```
 Administrative
 Claiming
```

Not sure how to format the cssSelector, use xpath to find this? Use something else? I'm stumped. Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: There is no link in your markup. Maybe your td is clickable?

Answer (score 2):

The `&nbsp;` is a non breakable space and it needs to be included. Here are multiple ways to get your link by text:

```
// by link text with 2 spaces at the begining and 3 spaces in the middle
WebElement ele1 = driver.findElement(By.linkText("  Administrative   Claiming"));

// by xpath with the caracter code of `&nbsp;`
WebElement ele2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[.='\u00A0\u00A0Administrative \u00A0\u00A0Claiming']"));

// by xpath by removing the `&nbsp;`
WebElement ele3 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[translate(.,'\u00A0','')='Administrative Claiming']"));
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks so much. I never ass-umed the two spaces and three. I thought it was one and two!

Answer (score 0):

nbsp is an encoded whitespace. You don't see it in the link because it gets automatically converted into ' '. I'm not sure I've understood your question, but you can easily get that field by id or class name:

```
driver.findElement(By.id(yourId));
```

**EDIT**

Alternatively you could get that by class name:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.className(className));
```

Notice that this will get you back all the elements of that class. Then you can iterate them and check the text to match your case.

Comment: Just using that id won't work. The HTML was incomplete. I have updated it in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Use xpath contains. Maybe something along the lines of

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(., 'Administrative') and contains(., 'Claiming')]"));
```

Comment: That results in odd behavior. It finds it because it's not erroring out but the .click() isn't having any effect either. It just does nothing. Normally if I click on this link it will expand a list of sub-links below it. Simply nothing is happening. Very frustrating!

Answer (score 0):

@PeterCook if you want you could use the onclick. Try

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("*[onclick='return TrackChanges();']")).click
```

Do you need to use the text?

Answer (score 0):

```java
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(translate(., '\u00A0', ' '), 'Administrative Claiming')]"));
```

For an explanation see my answer here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48897167/1168270)