# using Selenium webdriver to find elements with &nbsp;

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, automation

Hope you're all well. I'm quite new to selenium and a complete newbie to stack overflowso i hope i'm not disobeying any rules here.

I am trying to create a test framework and some tests using the following

c#, selenium webdriver, specflow, nunit

I am currently running a query against a sql server DB to retrieve some text and then trying to use that text to verify and search for that element on the site. The problem i have is that the site has the element html encoded

For example:

Data retrieved from the database could be something like - "Alumina MB China metallurgical grade delivered...."

The element on the site is as follows -

```html
<span class="com">Alumina&nbsp;MB&nbsp;China&nbsp;metallurgical&nbsp;grade&nbsp;delivered&nbsp;duty&nbsp;paid&nbsp;RBM/tonne</span>
```

Does anyone know how i could parse the data retrieved from the DB into the findElement command to easily find this element on the site whilst it contains `&nbsp;`

Look forward to hearing from you.

Many Thanks
Suban

Comment: Can you show what you have done so far?

Comment: so far i've tried

driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//*[@class='com' and text()='Alumina&nbsp;MB&nbsp;China&nbsp;metallurgical&nbsp;grade&nbsp;delivered&nbsp;duty&nbsp;paid&nbsp;RBM/tonne']"));

Comment: Hello Suban. Maybe the Replace method could help in your case. `string htmlString = dataBaseString.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;");`

Comment: Hi @Y-BCause, i have tried searching for the element as the following in chrome but couldn't find the element - //*[@class='com' and text()='Alumina&nbsp;MB&nbsp;China&nbsp;metallurgical&nbsp;g‌​rade&nbsp;delivered&‌​nbsp;duty&nbsp;paid&‌​nbsp;RBM/tonne']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to escape html characters by using **System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode**

it works for me:

```
var escaped = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(".//span[text()='Alumina&nbsp;MB&nbsp;China&nbsp;metallurgical&nbsp;grade&nbsp;delivered&nbsp;duty&nbsp;paid&nbsp;RBM/tonne']");
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(escaped));
```

Answer (score 0):

you should first replace all instances of `$nbsp;` in your xpath string to  and then search for that

Answer (score 0):

```cs
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[contains(@class'com') and normalize-space(translate(., '\u00A0', ' '))='Alumina MB China metallurgical grade delivered']"));
```

Explanation:
Use xpath to find a `span` element with class containing the string `com`, get the text from that (`.`) replace all of the `&nbsp` characters (i.e. unicode `\u00A0`) with a regular `space` character, and strip leading and trailing whitespace (this last part may not be needed in your situation).

Note: the string that should go in the single quotes after the `=` should only contain regular spaces.