# Selenium webdriver Unable to identify elements by xpath containing &nbsp;

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have following table row. I am unable to identify **th** using XPath.

```
<tr>
<th>My&nbsp;Home</th>
<th>My&nbsp;School</th>
<th>Home</th>
</tr>
```

I have tried  :

```
mydriver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr/th[text()='My Home']"));
mydriver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr/th[text()='My\u00a0Home']"));
mydriver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr/th[text()='My${nbsp}Home']"));
```

I have also tried contains() inside xpath.

Comment: You are changing your question every single minute how can you expect someone to answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below workaround

```
//th[starts-with(text(), "My") and substring(text(), 4)="Home"]
```

But note that it just allows you to skip `&nbsp;` identification

If you not familiar with this syntax, it means *`th` node with text that starts with substring `"My"` and starting from 4-th character the text is equal to `"Home"`*

Answer (score 1):

To to identify `th` with text as **`My&nbsp;Home`**  you can try either of the following :

```
mydriver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr/th[contains(text(),'Home')]"));
```

OR

```
mydriver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr/th[contains(.,'Home')]"));
```

> **Note** : In **`Java`** it's **`xpath`** not **`Xpath`**

Answer (score 1):

I have answered a very similar question to this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48897167/1168270)

tldr;

```java
mydriver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr/th[translate(text(),'\u00A0', ' ')='My Home']"));
```

This replaces the non-breaking spaces (`&nbsp;`) with a real space  and matches the string against the result.